# C# Newly created file is not found

Tags: c#

When I call `ConvertReposITDoc(398)` in my console app `ExportDoc(398)` works fine, a file is created on disk however `ConvertDoc(398)` is not able to find the file... but it definately exists.  Why?  How to fix?

```
  public void ConvertReposITDoc(int docId)
  {
      ExportDoc(docId);
      ConvertDoc(docId);
  }

  public void ExportDoc(int docId)   //Exports .djvu file from Documents db to disk
  {
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_appDb))
      {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDocumentRetrieveToDiskByDocId", conn))
          {
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = docId;
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNC_Path", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = @"\\MyMachine\C$\Temp\";
              conn.Open();
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
      }
  }

  public void ConvertDoc(int docId)  //Uses IrfanView command line to convert the .djvu doc to .pdf
  {
      ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
      Process Process;
      ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(String.Format("C:\\temp\\IrfanView\\i_view64.exe C:\\temp\\{0}.djvu /convert=C:\\temp\\{0}.pdf", docId.ToString()));
      ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
      Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
  }
```

Comment: `Process` is going to use a different user with different permissions.

Comment: What machine is \\MyMachine?

Comment: maybe run the code as admin?

Comment: I'd suggest retrieving the bytes from SQL Server, then writing them to a file with .NET. Then you can use the same variable as the destination file path and source file path for the conversion.

You also wouldn't be using SQL Server to write a file to disk -- I don't believe it's optimal to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProcessStartInfo()` can't accept parameters for a command line in the format originally posted.
Putting the parameters into the `ProcessInfo.Arguments` property resolved it.